# Selling photos with Store and Channel Images

Tags: expresso-store, image-galleries, channel-images

Embarking on a site that will sell photos. Those photos will be uploaded in bulk using Channel Images. The user will only want to pick their own photo. All photos will cost the same and should be given to the user post checkout by download.

What's the best way to approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used Store but from what I know of it, you should be able to add a product modifier.

Easiest way would be to add a Store field to your channel that has the Channel Images field.

Then you would add a modifier to grab the id Channel Images photo id.

Once customer has paid, you could display their order info, grab that id and run it through a Channel Images tag so they can download it.

If that makes any sense?

Comment: where would the photo id come from?

Comment: when you upload images with Channel Images, the id is assigned automatically I believe. You could also use the image count as well. Bear in mind you may want to store more than id as well. I know you said user would only purchase 1 image but you'd be as well giving them the option for more off the bat...more revenue that way too ;-)